# Kafka hangs when Committing Messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I have been trying to get started with Kafka. I have set up an 0.8.2 broker as per the quick start. With a single node broker I am able to run the scripts in the bin folder to successfully produce and consume messages.

I then tried to write some Scala code to use the new Producer API to produce messages. However nothing seemed to appear on the consumer. I modified the producer code to wait for the broker's metadata response. That blocks and then times out after 60 seconds.

The only difference I can see apart from using the new Producer API is all my previous tests were run inside the VM Kafka is installed on. Where as my code is running on the host machine and connecting into Kafka. I put some code into get the topics metadata to confirm connectivity to Kafka. That prints the topic metadata correctly. I have also checked the topic is set for a replication factor of 1. I can't see anything in the Kafka logs either.

Anyone got any ideas what might be making Kafka fail to commit the messages?

Bellow is the producer code:

```
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.1.0.180:9092")
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test","The Message")

val partions = producer.partitionsFor("test2").asScala.toList

partions.foreach((p:PartitionInfo) => println(s"${p.partition} ${p.replicas.length}"));

val offest = producer.send(record).get().offset()

println(s"Offset $offest")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I had tried that already. I have now worked out what the issue was.

The Hostname of the VM was not resolvable from my local machine. I had configured the code to connect via the VMs IP address which worked fine. Hence it could get the topic metadata. Unfortunately it was advertising the partition leaders using the VMs hostname. Hence when it came to posting a message onto the queue it timed out contacting the the leader node.

The fix was simply to add the VMs hostname to the local machines hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting zookeeper and kafka broker?